# Enterprise Architect Communication Diagrams question

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, communication-diagram

I want to achieve something like this in Enterprise Architect's Communication Diagrams:

```
   start()    ----------------    1. create()   ------------
------------> | RGController | ---------------> | U : User |
              ----------------                  ------------
```

But I am facing 2 problems:

1. It seems I have to always make a
   connection between 2 objects (I
   can't have the start() message just
   come out of nowhere, like I'd want).
2. I can't control the numbering as I'd
   want. Is there any way I could just
   set the numbering by myself? If I
   define that an actor is calling
   `start()` on `RGController`, it will
   call it message 1 when I'd want
   message 1 to be `User.create()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Which Object is sending the start() message to RGController?  Add it to the diagram and create the connection between these two objects.

Alternatively you could send the initial message from an Inital element (in the Activity toolbox).

You could also hack an invisible start element by creating an empty shape rendering script.

Just create a new Stereotype in Settings->UML...->Stereotypes, set the name to hidden, applied to , and set the shape script as:

```
shape main {
}
```

Then apply this stereotype to your initial element.  It should be rendered as invisible.

B) I'm not sure how to manually set the message labeling.  Are you aware of the message numbering settings?

- right clicking one of the message
  labels an selecting "Sequence
  Communication Messages".
- checking "start new group" in the
  Message Properties->Sequnce
  Expressions section.

Comment: I don't know which object is doing that (yet). Maybe an actor. Isn't there just a way to not having to put anything at all? EA seems quite restrictive. And what about the numbering system? I mean, I can live well with a), but I really need a way to be able to handle differently the numbering of the messages.

Comment: Perhaps send from the Initial element in the Activity toolbox or the End Point element from the Interaction toolbox.

Comment: About B), I want my first message to not count for the total numbering, so I only want User.create() to be my 1. message. I can't seem to achieve that.

Comment: Hmmm - yeah that seems tricky.  I've been able to set the start() message 0.1 and the create() as 1.  It seems hacky but here it is: create the start message association last - then move it up to the first message in the "sequence communication messages" dialog.

Comment: Isn't there a way to take that 0.1 off ?:(

Comment: Sorry mate - all out of ideas :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to draw an architecture which uses a Front-controller or Facade for handling incoming request?
If so in that case the client will call the start(). E.g. In case of an ASP.net application, it will be the UI code or presentation logic.

Client/User/Customer  ---start()---> RGBController--- create() ---> u: User

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Yes, the client will be calling the RGController.start(). But how can I make a message appear out of nowhere? It always forces me to do messages between 2 objects.

Comment: In UML, the message is from one object/actor to another. It doesn't come out of nowhere in the real software, so it can't come out of nowhere in the model.